# Trying to pull parameters from a LMS Message getting null

Tags: lightning-web-components, subscriber, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

I am trying to pull 2 parameters from an LMS message. Currently they are coming in as null at the way I am grabbing them. The publish and subscribe methods work, as I threw console statements to track everything, but I am seeing an error when I try to assign the vars as null from my apex class that uses them..

**Publisher JS**:

```
handleClickedMedia(event){
     let selectedIdValue = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-key");
     this.newMediaId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-key");
     const message = {
          mediaId: selectedIdValue, mediaList:this.mediaList
     };
     publish(this.messageContext, navigationMessageChannel, message);
     publish(this.dataMessageContext, dataMessageChannel, message);
}
```

**Handler JS**:

```
subscription = null;
  @wire(messageContext)
  messageContext;
  subscribeToMessageChannel(){
        if(!this.subscription){
              this.subscription = subscribe(
                    this.messageContext,
                    dataMessageChannel,
                    (message) => this.handleMessage(message),
                    {scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE}
              );
        }
  }
handleMessage(message){
     this.mediaId = message.mediaId;
     thhis.mediaList = message.mediaList;
}
```

**also tried** :

```
handleMessage(message)(){
         this.mediaId = message.parameters.mediaId;
         thhis.mediaList = message.parameters.mediaList;
    }
```

Comment: also tried message.details.mediaId; and message.detail.mediaId;

Comment: How are you handling subscribing to the message channel? Are you passing in `{message} => this.handleMessage(message)`? What does `console.log(message)` show in `handleMessage`?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Yes I am handling the message channel similar to this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_subscribe      when I console.log(JSON.stringify(message) I get the ' "mediaId" : "123", "mediaList" :"1234" '

Comment: Can you also add the method that subscribes to this `message-channel`?

Comment: @SachinHooda sure, give me a moment to add

Comment: I see something `handleMessage(message)(){` ?? should be `handleMessage(message){` ^^^

Comment: @SachinHooda I added the method that subs to the channel, I also tried running the subscribeToMessageChannel and the handleMesage both as async functions incase my apex callout method ran before it could assign the vars. But it still yielded the same result as "Null Null" for placement of mediaId and mediaList

Comment: @SachinHooda sorry, was a typo. Just updated

Comment: What's the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) {status: 500, body:{}, headers:{}}  body: exceptionType "System.NullPointerException" isUserDefinedException: false message: "null argument for JSONGenerator.writeStringField()" stackTrace: "(System Code) \n Class MediaController.retrieveMediaInfo.cls   Just to point out, if I hard code values for mediaId and mediaList the apex function calls out to my api and works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, the issue was that the mediaList and mediaID would become null because of the connectedcallback they were in. I moved the function callout to after the assigning of vars and it fixed it.